# ls -F command not consistent

Tags: command-line

Running `ls --help` is of little help to clarify what `ls -F` does.

> -F, --classify append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries.

Thus, I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670096/what-is-ls-f-ls-classify) thread to find it out, whose answer states

> -F      Display a slash ('/') immediately after each pathname that is a
>            directory, an asterisk ('*') after each that is executable, an at
>            sign ('@') after each symbolic link, a percent sign ('%') after
>            each whiteout, an equal sign ('=') after each socket, and a
>            vertical bar ('|') after each that is a FIFO.

Assuming it is correct, I don't understand why the output I get from `ls -F` is:

```
'List 1.pdf'*  'List 2.pdf'*  'List 3.pdf'*  'List 4.pdf' 'List 5.pdf'* 'List 6.pdf'
```

Since they're all pdf files, why some of them are marked as executable? Shouldn't all be marked the same way?

Comment: And in case you're wondering about the `>` suffix, it's used for Solaris _doors_ (which are a form of IPC similar to pipes and sockets). It's not used on other operating systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since they're all pdf files, why some of them are marked as executable? Shouldn't all be marked the same way?

Having the 'executable' marking is not caused by nor does depend on them being PDF files!

Instead, *ls* shows the asterisk if the file's *permissions* have the +x bit set for any group. That is, if you run `ls -l` on the same files you will see `rwxr-xr-x` instead of `rw-r--r--`. You can change this using `chmod`.

However, *it is* completely pointless to mark a PDF file as 'executable' because it doesn't actually have any OS-executable code (and if you tried actually executing any of those files, you'd get an error message of some sort).

The most likely reason they have the +x permission bit is by accident: either because you've copied them from a Windows disk (due to Windows setting +x on all files by default), or from other kind of storage that doesn't store file permissions at all (e.g. a FAT32 USB stick).

*(Whether a FAT32 disk will show up on Linux with files having +x or -x depends on mount options such as 'fmask=0133'. Unfortunately fmask=0 is the default, resulting in a useless +x.)*

Comment: You have surely nailed it, I indeed copied them from a FAT32 USB stick, except for the files List4.pdf and List6.pdf, which are not marked with the asterisk.